# Can one battery bank be connected to two static UPS devices?

Tags: batteries, inverter, rectifier, ups, redundancy

To make a redundant static uninterruptible power supply (UPS) configuration such as pictured below, I have seen warnings in UPS manuals that each UPS is to be connected to its own battery bank.

But is it okay that for this configuration I'd remove the battery of the second UPS, and put a jumper so that the battery of the first UPS is also connected to the second UPS?

[image: Redundant UPS Configuration]

Answer (score 1):

You would reduce the redundancy of the system by relying on a single battery bank.

Also, the battery chargers in the two UPSs may interfere with each other, and may not properly charge the battery bank.

Comment: Also a chance of blowing a fuse. UPS's take the cheap way out and share SCR's with both charging and as back-up functions, and do some wave shaping so output is closer to a sine wave. The batteries actually float compared to Earth ground.